# how to access scripted field value in another script field

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to create a Scripted Field like :

`return doc[scripted_field_a].value+doc[scripted_field_b].value`

how to access to scripted field value in painless script ?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I was just trying to do the same but after giving it some thought made me realize that making it possible would mean that Elastic would have to analyze the reference invocation graph to figure out the correct order of field calculation.

E.g. What would happen if one tried to reference fieldA from fieldB and vice versa (i.e. create a loop)?

Comment: I think you're right

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in field a to script b.

```
// use script of script field a put to a function to get value
int script_a() { return doc['x'] * 2; }

//main section of script b
script_a() + 2
```